# How to make my if statement run once in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a simplified mock banking terminal application for a class in python. I'm trying to make it so that if they have a checking or savings account they cannot create a new one. I have tried setting cacc_check to a global variable in both the `if loop_set` and outside of the while loop. When I try that it complains that `cacc_check` hasn't been initialized before it has been used. When I have `cacc_check =` in `if menu_choice == 1` it will reset it to 0 every time I enter that loop. I'm not sure how to initialize `cacc_check` so that it won't get reset to 0 every time I enter that menu and still be able to be used in the `if acc_choice == 1 and cacc_check != 0' so that any account number generated is not wiped out. This is where I'm stuck right now:

```
import random
loop_set = 1

while loop_set < 5:

def homeScreen():
    print('Welcome to your bank application \n 1. Create Account \n 2. Make a Deposit \n 3. Make a Withdrawal \n'
          ' 4. View Accounts \n 5. View Transactions \n 6. Transfer Money \n 7. Loans \n 8. Close an Account')
    menu_choice = int(input('Please enter a number to select an option'))
    if menu_choice == 0:
        homeScreen()
    if menu_choice == 1:
        cacc_check = 0
        sacc_check = 
        print('Creating Account')
        name = str(input('Please enter your name: '))
        acc_choice = int(input('Type 1 for a checking account and 2 for a savings account'))
        if acc_choice == 1 and cacc_check == 0:
            cacc_num = random.randint(1000, 9999)
            cacc_check += 1
            print('Hello ', name, 'your checking account number is', cacc_num)
            homeScreen()
        if acc_choice == 1 and cacc_num != 0:
            print("It looks like you already have a checking account with us")
            homeScreen()
        if acc_choice == 2 and sacc_check == 0:
            sacc_num = random.randint(1000, 9999)
            print('Hello ', name, 'your savings account number is', sacc_num)

    if loop_set == 1:
        loop_set = loop_set + 1
        print('loop_set = ', loop_set)
        homeScreen()
```

I'd like to be able to ensure that it can only run through the statement assigning a random account number once, or else that account number will get overwritten next time it goes through. I apologize in advance for bad formatting and optimization. I'm sure there are better ways to accomplish what I'm trying to do but I'm still learning. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The current code in your question doesn't make much sense. Please read the guidance on how to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the variables to before the `while` loop. That way the values don't get reset each time the loop runs. Try something like:

```
import random

def homeScreen():
    print('Welcome to your bank application \n 1. Create Account \n 2. Make a Deposit \n 3. Make a Withdrawal \n'
          ' 4. View Accounts \n 5. View Transactions \n 6. Transfer Money \n 7. Loans \n 8. Close an Account')

def loopScreen():
    menu_choice = int(input('Please enter a number to select an option'))
    loop_set = 1
    cacc_check = 0
    sacc_check = 0

    while loop_set < 5:
        if menu_choice == 0:
            homeScreen()
        if menu_choice == 1:
            print('Creating Account')
            name = str(input('Please enter your name: '))
            acc_choice = int(input('Type 1 for a checking account and 2 for a savings account'))
            if acc_choice == 1 and cacc_check == 0:
                cacc_num = random.randint(1000, 9999)
                cacc_check += 1
                print('Hello ', name, 'your checking account number is', cacc_num)
                homeScreen()
            if acc_choice == 1 and cacc_num != 0:
                print("It looks like you already have a checking account with us")
                homeScreen()
            if acc_choice == 2 and sacc_check == 0:
                sacc_num = random.randint(1000, 9999)
                print('Hello ', name, 'your savings account number is', sacc_num)

        if loop_set == 1:
            loop_set = loop_set + 1
            print('loop_set = ', loop_set)
            homeScreen()


loopScreen()
```